# C# run piece of code under different credential

Tags: c#, credentials

Referring to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168571/run-code-as-a-different-user-c) I was able to execute some code as different user.
Now I'm trying to execute a piece of code as a user with administrator privileges and I get a missing file error. The code is this:

```
using (new Impersonator("domainAdmin", "DOMAIN", "myStup1dPa$$w0rd"))
{
    GetXAApplicationByName apps = new GetXAApplicationByName();
    apps.BrowserName = new string[] { "*" };
    IEnumerable<XAApplication> result = CitrixRunspaceFactory.DefaultRunspace.ExecuteCommand(apps);
    // other code...
}
```

The error is thrown at last reported line, the one starting with `IEnumerable<XAApplication>` and is:

> FileNotFoundException not handled C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll

I don't report code for `Impersonator` class, the basic schema is reported on linked question (and it worked also in other applications).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this link help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783213/impersonation-throws-filenotfoundexception-with-windowsidentity-in-powershell?

Comment: the problem seems to be similar, but the user I'm impersonating is already local administrator

Comment: Is Windows Powershell installed?

Comment: Yes it is (version 2)

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no problem with impersonating but your code somehow tries to load the assembly System.Management.Automation.dll which is not in GAC , can you try registering this assembly in GAC and try it out again .

Comment: it's already registered in GAC, and running it without impersonating does work

Comment: is it possible for you to catch the exception and see the complete error message (including inner exceptions) using exception.ToString() and see whether you are able to get any info